# Overwrite ExecStartPre= in systemd drop-in

Tags: debian, nginx, systemd

I would like to add a systemd drop-in to `nginx.service` under Debian (Buster). A contained `ExecStartPre=` directive should create an Nginx configuration file from a template before the server starts up.

The trouble I am facing is that `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` already contains an `ExecStartPre=`, which checks the validity of Nginx configuration files. Since it is executed before the `ExecStartPre=` from my drop-in and since the Nginx configuration file is not yet complete at this point, `systemctl start nginx.service` fails.

How can I instruct systemd to execute my `ExecStartPre=` first (or to forget about the `ExecStartPre=` from `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`)?

**UPDATE** [`ExecCondition=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) seems promising, but is apparently not available in my version (241) of systemd.

Comment: Can't you run 2 commands on ExecStartPre by using `&&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [systemd.service man page on `ExecStart=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) (same syntax):

> If the empty string is assigned to this option, the
> list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this
> option will have no effect.

So the solution is to add `ExecStartPre=` to your drop-in, before specifying `ExecStartPre=whatever`.

Comment: Yep, just noticed it and was about to write up my own answer. Thx.